# Data wouldn't post

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm trying to import a keyword to my database slot which is empty, but it is not saving and I'm getting the `Failed to save in database` message.

```js
router.post('/newkeyword/:search', (req, res) => {
  var myData = User(req.keyword);
  myData.save()
    .then(item => {
      res.send(`${req} saved in database`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send('Failed to save in database')
    })
})
```

Comment: pass your field key with value like `User({'field_name': req.keyword})`, Please improve your question..

Comment: Please read this [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).